# iReport / Jasperserver

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a report designed in ireport that is using the "current_date" option from the pallet. I have two of these on my report. One formatted for date MM/dd/yyyy the other "h.mm a". The preview in report designer works fine. I add the report to jasperserver and run the report from their and the formatting is removed and i get to spelled out date fields.

EDIT: Relevant XML portion added...

```
<textField pattern="MM/dd/yyyy">
    <reportElement x="406" y="29" width="165" height="14"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: Can you post the snippet of your report template?

Comment: @Alex - Added the XML part for one of the date fields. If you meant something else let me know.

Comment: I've tested empty report (without datasource) with JRS 4.2.1. Everything is ok for `MM/dd/yyyy`, `dd/MM/yyyy` and `h.mm a` patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still an issue. I can get the system to work fine with the formatting from within iReport but when the same report is run from jasperserver the formatting is ignored. I have worked around this by just providing the date pre-formatted in my application before passing it to jasper. I am closing since i do have a work around and the question has received little activity.